# Navigate page upon condition

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have to navigate page based upon condition, here I get response from my backend and when I try to evaluate this it behaves continuous looping but not getting exact result. What I did till now is:

```js
constructor (public homeauth: Authservice, public navCtrl: NavController) {
  this.accesscheck();
}

accesscheck() {
  this.homeauth.accesscheck().then(response => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      if (response[i]["c20"] !== true) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot("TabsPage");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I have response from my backend like this:

```js
[
    {
        "c24": true,
        "statuscode": 65544
    },
    {
        "c23": true,
        "statuscode": 4259848
    },
    {
        "c22": true,
        "statuscode": 6357000
    },
    {
        "c21": true,
        "statuscode": 7405576
    },
    {
        "c20": true,
        "statuscode": 7929864
    },
    {
        "c19": true,
        "statuscode": 8192008
    },
    {
        "c18": true,
        "statuscode": 8323080
    }
]
```

my backend code something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you check response[i]["c20"] !== true in an object that might not even have a "c20" property. So you should first check if the response[i] object **has** that property.

Also, after you have navigated to the desired page, you should `break;` your for loop:

```
accesscheck() {
  this.homeauth.accesscheck().then(response => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      if (response[i]["c20"] !== null) {
          if (response[i]["c20"] !== true) {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot("TabsPage");
            break;
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I try this one but it iterates still all objects in the loop then finally navigate to tabs page so its pushing multiple times the same page. something behaves very strange.

Comment: did you check it this with the above array of objects

Comment: Well no, but I think that the problem is that you check response[i]["c20"] !== true in an object that might not even have a "c20" property. Check the updated answer.

Comment: you are right what you said but still i have same problem. I check with console, the loop enters even if condition is not true in this case. Here i have response with c20 is true. the loop enters even c20 is not equal to true. something behaves very starnge.

Comment: The condition if (response[i]["c20"] !== true) 
will be true even for elements such as "c20": true. The reason for that is that 
response[i]["c20"] does not exist, so it is not true. Did you try with the extra check I added?

Comment: I check that one exact what you posted here i got only get response with true values so i just check based on numbers (Ex:c20,c21,c22) like that if those numbers in my response i must continue with the current page. If those numbers not in my response i need to navigate to homepage. here i am checking page access based on those numbers. you can see my backend response in above image.

Comment: Can you please also post the console output of your response object?

Comment: Sure. What was the problem eventually? Can you also vote my answer as the correct one?

Comment: The problem is for me its not working looping all objects at a time and evaluate based on condition what i did i have passed key and values in function its return if any object found otherwise it is return null. Based on this i give permission to user weather you can access or not. for my task your answer not working that's why i did not give correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping too many times. If you have more than one "false" statement in your data, you will end up navigating to the tabspage more than one time. You should either **break** out of the loop after you have encountered the first false, or you should set up a boolean value like "navigatedToTabsPage" which is initially set to false, but evaluates to true inside the **if** statement and thus terminates the loop (you would have to nest another if statement if so)

Answer (score 0):

Its working something like this

```
findObjectByKey(array, key, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i][key] === value) {
          return array[i];
      }
  }
  return null;
}

   accesscheck() {
    this.homeauth.accesscheck().then(response => {
      this.obj = this.findObjectByKey(response, 'c77', true);
      if(this.obj){
        console.log("success")
      }else{
        this.navCtrl.setRoot("TabsPage");
      }
    });
  }
```

i have passed this accesscheck() in constructor.